# Parsing html for domain links

Tags: python

I have a script that parses an html page for all the links within it. I am getting all of them fine, but I have a list of domains I want to compare it against. So a sample list contains

```
list=['www.domain.com', 'sub.domain.com']
```

But I may have a list of links that look like

```
http://domain.com
http://sub.domain.com/some/other/page
```

I can strip off the http:// just fine, but in the two example links I just posted, they both should match. The first I would like to match against the www.domain.com, and the second, I would like to match against the subdomain in the list.

Right now I am using url2lib for parsing the html. What are my options in completely this task?

Comment: How do you decide if `domain.com` should match against `www.domain.com` or `sub.domain.com`?

Comment: For this purpose I am going with the assumption if there is no subdomain showing on the domain.com, to associate it with www

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider stripping 'www.' from the `list` and doing something as simple as:

```
url = 'domain.com/'
for domain in list:
    if url.startswith(domain):
        ... do something ...
```

Or trying both wont hurt either I spose:

```
url = 'domain.com/'
for domain in list:
    domain_minus_www = domain
    if domain_minus_www.startswith('www.'):
        domain_minus_www = domain_minus_www[4:]
    if url.startswith(domain) or url.startswith(domain_minus_www):
        ... do something ...
```

Comment: startswith should do just fine. Thank you!

Comment: Will fail on `domain.com.phisher198313.com`. Use the `urlparse` module instead.

Comment: @max good point.  @hallik, you might want to follow max's advice, but a similar concept of looping and removing the 'www.' will apply

Comment: Actually scratch that - you're checking for a slash separating the domain from the path already, so the problem won't occur. I was going by the strings specified in the question. Still, my advice on using `urlparse` applies, as it is the standard method of comparing URLs.

Comment: no, actually, you're right.  My test url has a slash, not my matcher urls... heh

Comment: I will test with both solutions, and look into urlparse too. Thanks guys!